# Calculate the eccentricity of ellipses

Tags: r, geometry, geometry-surface

I've like to calculate the eccentricity of ellipses x, in my example:

```
#Artificial ellipse
a <- 1 # semi-major axis 
e <- x# eccentricity 
b <- a * sqrt(1 - e^2) # semi-minor axis
c <- 1.3 # ellipse area
```

But I need to make this using the ellipse area (c) in the calculation. This is poisible?

Comment: Eccentricity is a measure of how much a shape (cones, parabola's, etc) differs from a true (i.e. original) circle. Do you link this with ellipse area?

Comment: Yes my basic idea is make this by the use of area (area= minor axis * major axis * pi) and eccentricity definitions.

Comment: You cannot calculate eccentricity using only area. What parameters are known?

Comment: MBo my parameters was area, minor and major axis.

Comment: But ....if you have both axes, you don't need area to find eccentricity. What is exact problem formulation?

Comment: MBo I don't know I can calculate the eccentricity?

Comment: same homework here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675591/simulation-of-ellipse-axis

Answer (score 0):

```
b = c/(pi*a);
x = (sqrt(a^2 - b^2))/a;
```

is the formula you need. Or put togther:

```
x = (sqrt(a^2 - (c/(pi*a))^2))/a;
```